# Seems like everytihing is working except the addition

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  int LoanValue, LoanRate, LoanValue2;
  cout << "Loan: ";
  cin >> LoanValue;
  cout << "Loan Rate: ";
  cin >> LoanRate;
  LoanValue2 = LoanValue+(LoanValue*(LoanRate/100));
  cout << LoanValue << ", " << LoanValue2 << ", " << LoanValue2/12;
}
```

If the input was 6000 then it outputs 6000, 6000 and 5000. It just doesn't see as if LoanValue2 actually executes the addition. Have no idea what is wrong with it

EDIT: Got it. Done this:

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   using namespace std;

   int main() 
   {
      int LoanValue, LoanRate;
      double LoanValue2;
      cout << "Loan: ";
      cin >> LoanValue;
      cout << "Loan Rate: ";
      cin >> LoanRate;
      LoanValue2 = LoanValue+(LoanValue*(double(LoanRate)/100));
      cout << LoanValue << ", " << LoanValue2 << ", " << LoanValue2/12;
    }
```

Comment: what was the input for `LoanRate` ?

Comment: Input was 5. Sorry for forgetting

Comment: If you have problems  with calculations, break them up and print intermediate results or debug.

Answer (score 3):

As all your variables are integers, you are using integer division here:

```
LoanValue2 = LoanValue+(LoanValue*(LoanRate/100));
```

e.g. if `LoanRate` is `5`, then `5/100 == 0`. You can fix it by using `double` variables.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an integer divide, which will produce an integer result of 0 if LoanRate is below 100. Replace with 100.0 to do a floating-point divide instead.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Only just learnt C++ coming from python.

Comment: @Yalnix Note that this will still give you wrong results in some cases, unless you want to cut digits on purpose. The result `LoanRate2` is still integer, thus eg `LoanRate2 = 10.123` will result in `LoanRate2 == 10`

Comment: So use your solution if you don't want to cut off the two digits. Got it.

Comment: @tobi303 Like this:   double LoanValue2; and then at LoanValue2: 
  LoanValue2 = LoanValue+(LoanValue*(double(LoanRate)/100));